# Produce all numbers that meet specific criteria

Tags: c#, random, integer

I have tried posting before, but after editing the question 5 times it got cloudy and did not help anyone. So I will ask properly this time so please consider the help (If you believe this is a duplicate, then do so for the older post that is only making things worse)

Firstly I want to make a very simple program using C# that will randomly display all the numbers that qualify for ALL the following criteria:

1.Number generated must be between 1123 and 5543 inclusive

2.Number generated must only have digits 1,2,3,4 and 5

3.Number generated must not be repeated

4.Each number must have one of its digits repeated ( as in 1146 or 2627) not more

When I did some maths, I came up with the conclusion that there are **exactly 300** numbers that fit here.

The following code does part of the job: It Produces a 4 digit number with only the digits 1-5. But there are 3 other rules needed that I don't know how to enforce. It is my first time using C#, (only VB.Net in the past) so I have no idea how to go further.

```
var chars = "12345";
var stringChars = new char[4];
var random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
{
stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
}
var finalString = new String(stringChars);
Console.WriteLine(finalString)
```

Just the thing about `Console.WriteLine`, I don't really care how the output is displayed. I saw a suggestion stating I export the data into a `.txt` file, but all I am concerned with is *seeing* the numbers all at once, but separated (by breaks or commas or double spacing or anything) from each other.

What I mean by "randomly" at the beginning is not *completely* random; I mean random out of the 300 possibilities until all are finished.

It does not concern me whether they are in order or not, I am allowed to use some online service to order them once I'm done to make things easier.

---

Thanks in advance, and just a quick note, this is *not* a homework question because "allowed" and "required". The backstory is irrelevant to Stack Overflow so I omitted it.

Like I said, if you think this is a duplicate, it is not. The other post is gone too messy.

---

**EDIT:**

I tried solving again, and found there to be only 60 numbers. Here is what I did

(This is Maths but I put it there for understanding)

I place 4 dashes as slots for options.  _ _ _ _

For the first "slot" I have five options (1-5) so I write 5. Since a digit has to be repeated, then the next one has to be only option (I previously thought we still had 5 options there). So with one number out, 4 more to go since I can't have 2 repeated digits. Then there are only 3 for the last digit, so we are looking at 5,1,4,3 on my "slots". I then multiply them to get the total possibilities 5x1x4x3 = 60 total numbers.

I understand this may be irrelevant on this site, but I think it's necessary to know for the code to work.

---

Thanks again.

Comment: You say the program must "randomly display all the numbers that qualify" - what do you mean by "randomly display"?

Comment: Ah, you kind-of answered that. You don't really need any random behaviour, you just need a list of the qualifying numbers, right?

Comment: Frankly, the non-repetition clause is the biter here. That means that there is no *efficient* way of generating them on the fly. Given that (you say) there are exactly 300, the most appropriate thing to do seems to be to simply generate all 300, and either:

- put them *unsuffled* in a list and take from a random position in the list as required (removing that item)
- *shuffle* them at the start, and put them in a list/array/queue/whatever and simply take from the end each time (again, removing the item)

Comment: 300? Seems like 360...

Comment: @peeebeee I already said, there are 300 possible, so out of these a random one is drawn until all is good.

Comment: @InBetween I made a mistake. Read the edit.

Comment: There are definitely more possible numbers (360), check [here](https://output.jsbin.com/fenorowari)

Answer (score 5):

Try this code. It's create all numbers in a range and then shuffle it:

```
var validDigits = new HashSet<char> {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1123, 5543 - 1123 + 1)
    .Where(i => i.ToString().All(c => validDigits.Contains(c))) // only 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    .Where(i => i.ToString().Distinct().Count() == 3) // only one repeated number
    .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()) // shuffle numbers
    .ToArray();
```

Now you can print each number to console

```
foreach (var number in numbers)
  Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Comment: Side note: `.All(c => c >= '0'  && c <= '5')` looks simpler

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Agree with you. However `HashSet` is more flexible, it will require minimal change to allow `1, 2 and 9` numbers only, for example

Comment: Excuse the rookie please, I've never used C# before. Could you tell me how to then display the results?

Comment: @AleksAndreev Ur making me feel bad. I don't get it. Could you please add that to your answer? I only get the console.writeline part of the job.

Answer (score 2):

Aleks Andreev answer is great; here is an exclusively numerical approach using query syntax where all numbers are generated simply applying rules 2 and 4 (Rule 1 is redundant and 3 doesn’t apply):

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GenerateValidNumbers()
{
    var validDigits = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);

    return
        from thousands in validDigits
        from hundreds in validDigits
        from tens in validDigits
        from ones in validDigits
        where (new[] { thousands, hundreds, tens, ones}).Distinct()
                                                        .Count() == 3
        select thousands * 1000 + hundreds * 100 + tens * 10 + ones;
}
```

And now, a shuffled "random" sequence is produced the following way:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var randomSequenceOfNumbers = 
    GenerateValidNumbers().OrderBy(r => rnd.Next());
```

The number of combinations that comply with the specified rules is *360* by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the min and max for the range of numbers to be parsed (1123 and 5543), I would do a simple loop and check which numbers in this range qualify and add them to a list. You can then scramble the list to make it "random":

```
var numbers = new List<string>();
for (var i = 1123; i <= 5543; i++) {
    var testNumber = i.ToString();
    var hasOtherDigit = testNumber.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' }) != -1;
    var hasMoreThanTwoEqualDigits = testNumber.GroupBy(d => d).Where(d => d.Count() == 2).Count() != 1;
    if (!hasOtherDigit && !hasMoreThanTwoEqualDigits)
    {
        numbers.Add(testNumber);
    }
}

var rnd = new Random();
var cnt = 0;
numbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToList();

foreach (var number in numbers) {
    cnt++;
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", cnt, number));
}
```

By the way, I get 360 numbers in total.